# mysqli_num_rows doesn't show desired results

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a 'users' table in my Database (currently 4 users) that contains different roles (1 = user, 2= admin, 3= moderator). I want to show some lines of my php script only to admins and moderators, so I made this query:
(I know it is not secure)

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
$stuff = 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE role > 0';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $stuff);
```

This query list all users with the role over 0.

```
require_once('link_to_script.php');
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) >1){
echo "Admin area";
}else{
echo "No Permissions";
}
```

This should be self explaining (only show "Admin area" to users with role higher than 1)

I don't know what my mistake is and I hope someone could help me a little bit :)

Comment: If all you need is a count then do a `COUNT()`

Comment: This seem to be a logical error: You asks for the number of entries, and not about the content of role. So fi there are >=1 user with role>1, all become admin.

Comment: You also need to check that the *current logged in user* has that rank. Not just any user of role > 0.

Comment: @Wimm i thought something like that but i dont know how i could fix this

Answer (score 0):

You can use IN in your SQL Query, For example if you need admin and moderator use the following

```
 SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE role IN ('2','3')
```

**mysqli_num_rows** returning number of rows in result set.

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)){
   echo "Admin and moderator area";
}else{
  echo "No Permissions";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are saying you want more than 1 row, you probably want to say more than 0 rows or just 1 row...

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) >1){
```

Should be

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) >0){
```

or

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
```

As for *I know it is not secure* - as there are no bound parameters, the SQL cannot be influenced by any input and so there is not problems with security in this case.  BUT you will probably want to add in the logged in user at some point, this should be done with prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

I'am grabing the current user now with:

```
$userID = $page->users->currentUserId();
$stuff = 'SELECT role FROM `users` WHERE id = $userID';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $stuff;
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) >2){
....
```

Grabbing of the current userID is working but how can i compare it with the the role, that is needed ?

Comment: Please don't add further details as an answer - you will either need to add this to the question or ask a new question.   BUT you have 2 problems with this code - missing `)` in `$stuff;` - `$stuff);` and you would expected 1 row - so `($result) >0){` As in my answer - you need to check the number of rows and I wouldn't expect more than 1 row per user (especially not > 2)